# How to get the hwnd of WIn10 start menu in C++?

Tags: c++, windows-10, hwnd

I used FindWindowEx+ CLassname:Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow and caption: start menu to find the  hwnd of  win10 start menu, but return NULL, i wangt to get it's hwnd ,then i can get the rectangle,but i can't get the hwnd , there is anybody know how to get it in c++ code ,thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using Win32 API or UWP API? You can use Spy++ to find out more info about Windows 10's start menu. It can be launched from VS -> Tools -> Spy++

Comment: I used Win32 API FindWindowEx, it does't work. Spy++ can't find start menu of Win10 ,only find start button. So, there is a way to get the Rect of WIn10's Start menu? thanks a lot!

Comment: I've used a utility called WinID to help with stuff like this.  It updates in real time and can show details about the start menu/screen.  By far the easiest non-programmatic way I know of to grab the Start Menu's hWnd.  https://dennisbabkin.com/winid/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you, Spy++ could not find the handle of the start menu. And when the start menu is not displayed, the Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow window cannot be obtained. I found a solution, which is to display the start menu first, and then call the WindowFromPoint function to get the handle of the start menu.

```
    POINT point{ 0,1030 };  //Assuming your resolution is 1920*1080

    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0x45, NULL, NULL);  //show start menu
    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, NULL);

    Sleep(100);
    HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(point);  //get start menu hwnd
```